# WSO2: IS and APIM SAML SSO Error - Error when processing authentication request

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have setup WSO2 IS (5.6.0) and APIM (2.5.0) recently.

I have then tried to integrate both of them together so that IS can be used IDP and APIM can be logged in using SSO.

I did the changes according to this Link
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+Identity+Server+as+IDP+for+SSO)

Things look fine and I am accessing https://apim.com/publisher URL for login in, I am getting IS login page.
Then I enter, username and password, it authenticates as well but then I get below error in browser:

Error when processing authentication request! Please try again.

Below are the logs from backend:

DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SSOAuthnRequestAbstractValidator} -  Thread local tenant domain is set to: carbon.super
[2019-02-17 01:12:56,196] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} -  Authentication Request Validation is successful..
[2019-02-17 01:12:56,803] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : null
[2019-02-17 01:12:56,804] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  No SaaS SAML service providers found for the issuer : API_PUBLISHER. Checking for SAML service providers registered in tenant domain : carbon.super
[2019-02-17 01:12:56,825] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authentication request!
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error while reading service provider configurations for issuer : API_PUBLISHER in tenant domain : carbon.super

Can someone please check and let me know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't enabled **IdP initiated SSO** in the Service Provider configurations at the WSO2IS side. Find the attached service provider configuration screenshot below,

[image]